# css bounce and add class in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

what is wrong with my css,the bounce animation just doesn`t happen???
I want an image to bounce on click according to my css animation which is not happening

HTML CODE::

```
<div class="hair">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair1" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onclick="bounce();" >
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.hair{
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-35px);}
}
.bounce_css
{
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
function bounce(){
    alert("reached")
document.getElementById('hair1').style.WebkitAnimationName = 'bounce_css';
}
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what **is** and **should** happen with this code.

Comment: ok!!!i will edit the question

Comment: `document.getElementById('hair1').style.className = 'bounce_css';`

Comment: @epascarello:in the css above

Comment: Any error? ok try this too: `document.getElementById('hair1').style.WebkitAnimationName = 'bounce';`

Comment: naaa!!!nothing happening...any other solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect your code to look more like this

**CSS:**

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -o-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        -o-transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
.bounce_css {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
    -o-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function bounce() {
    document.getElementById('hair1').className = "animated bounce_css";
}
```

**Running Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GALU5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function bounce(){
    alert("reached")
    document.getElementById('hair1').classList.add('bounce_css');
}
```

Or:

```
function bounce(){
    alert("reached")
    document.getElementById('hair1').style.WebkitAnimationName = 'bounce';
}
```