# Javascript/CSS3 Transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

When 'image-strip' is hovered it opens to the height of it's contents. However, it's supposed to also have a smooth transition when doing so. What am I doing wrong? The CSS3 doesn't seem to be affecting it.

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hover(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.height="100%";
}
</script>
```

The Styles:

```
#image-strip{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#image-strip img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="image-strip" onmouseover="hover('image-strip')"><img src="images/content/1.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things, first one:
You can actually pass 'this' in to your function call because then you have access to it and do not need to access the DOM again saving time and memory, not a noticeable amount, but its a better practice.
`onmouseover="hover(this)"`

```
function hover(el) {
    el.style.height="100%";
}
```

Second thing:
CSS transitions are meant to be used without Javascript, the point is to not need JS to manipulate the DOM so to get a transition to work you would do:

```
#image-strip{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
   cursor: pointer;
}

#image-strip:hover {
   height: 100%;
}
```

You only need to call transition on the properties you want to affect and then when the element gets a state change, such as hover, the transition will kick in. Just to be clear you don't need any Javascript to use transitions unless you maybe add or remove an element to kick of a transition but you don't need any JS for what you are doing. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I still can't get it to work though. The reason I am using JS is because I want it to stay in the state of the hover and not return back when the cursor is moved away. Perhaps there is a way I can do this?

Comment: This is possible with a css animation but not transistion...that combined with a jquery onmouseenter event will do the trick...I will put together a fiddle to demo this later when I am in front of a computer

Comment: [codepen example](http://codepen.io/kkemple/pen/AxCao) here is a working example for what you need. let me know if you need clarification =]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="image-strip" onmouseover="hover(this.id)"><img src="images/content/1.jpg"></div>
```

STEP 2-->Your css(modified you id to class --># becomes .)

```
.image-strip{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

STEP 3-->JavaScript(just add you css class )

```
function hover(id) {
document.getElementById(id).classList.add('image-strip');
}
```

Just make sure you do the above changes,Your code will work.100%
I had the same problem,LINK-->[css bounce and add class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917457/css-bounce-and-add-class-in-javascript)

UPDATE 1-->

Apply your css with javascript,

```
document.getElementById(id).style.webkitTransitionDuration="0.6s";
document.getElementById(id).style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction="linear";
document.getElementById(id).style.cursor="pointer";
```

Comment: Still no luck :/ This starts the image as large as the image is, when hovered it goes back to the size I started with in the initial code I posted.

Comment: wat exactly are you doing??